# Specializing Generic Sealed Types

Tags: generics, scala, types

In Scala, I'd like to be able to define a generic type of abstract syntax tree nodes sort of like this

```
sealed abstract class AST[T <: AST[T]] {
    def child : List[T] ;
}

case class LeafAST[T <: AST[T]]( x : Int ) extends AST[T] {
    def child = Nil 
}

case class BranchAST[T <: AST[T]]( left : T, right : T ) extends AST[T] {
    def child = left :: right :: Nil
}
```

Now I can write generic code like this

```
def countLeaves[T <: AST[T]]( x : AST[T]) : Int = x match {
    case LeafAST( x ) => 1
    case BranchAST( left, right ) => countLeaves[T](left) + countLeaves[T](right) 
}
```

Now my first problem is that the keyword `sealed` seems to have no effect. If I omit a case from the match expression, there is no error. Why and how can I write what I want?  (I have other problems --e.g. how to specialize AST--, but I'll just stick to one problem per post.)

Comment: What Scala version are you using? 2.9.1.final doesn't seem to have this problem. I get the "match is not exhaustive" warning as expected. (BTW it's a warning and not an error.)

Comment: Because of your reply I upgraded to the Eclipse plug-in at http://download.scala-ide.org/releases/2.0.0-beta with a 2.9.2 tool-chain.  Still no _warning_ message if I miss a case.

Comment: The Eclipse plug-in beta is in active development and therefore has lots of features missing. I used the REPL and as I said earlier, it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help Agile.  You are right.  I was wrong about 2.9.2.  I now see the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error -- there is a **warning**. For example:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed abstract class AST[T <: AST[T]] {
    def child : List[T] ;
}

case class LeafAST[T <: AST[T]]( x : Int ) extends AST[T] {
    def child = Nil
}

case class BranchAST[T <: AST[T]]( left : T, right : T ) extends AST[T] {
    def child = left :: right :: Nil
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class AST
defined class LeafAST
defined class BranchAST

scala> def countLeaves[T <: AST[T]]( x : AST[T]) : Int = x match {
     |     case LeafAST( x ) => 1
     | }
<console>:10: warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination      BranchAST

       def countLeaves[T <: AST[T]]( x : AST[T]) : Int = x match {
                                                         ^
countLeaves: [T <: AST[T]](x: AST[T])Int
```

You can turn it into an error with the flag `-Xfatal-warnings`.

Comment: Thanks.  Either I was totally confused or needed to upgrade my system.  Either way I'm seeing the warning now.  Thanks to Daniel and agilesteel.